# Unable to make REST API calls on my server from my Ionic 3.0 Windows Emulator

Tags: cordova, ionic3

I cannot make HTTP calls from my Ionic app. The HTTP calls work when I run app on browser but fails on an emulator. I get the following error response:

[image]

**NOTE: I use HttpClientModule from @angular/common/http**

I have tried the following solutions

1. Downgrading to [UIWebView](https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/#downgrading-to-uiwebview)
2. Adding [Cordova whitelist plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/)
3. Adding/removing Windows platform
4. Adding **allow-navigation** tags in config.xml

None of the above works for me.

I am able to call a sample GitHub API like the following:

```html
this.http.get("http://api.github.com").subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
}, err=> {
      console.log(err);
});
```

But when I try to hit the node app running on port 3000 my remote server like below, the call fails:

```js
this.http.get("http://10.100.16.118:3000").subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
}, err=> {
      console.log(err);
});
```

However I am able to hit this URL on my browser successfully:

[image]

Some pointers:

1. I have set CORS headers on my NodeJS app
2. I am able to hit the API endpoints from browser
3. I am able to hit the API endpoints when I run ionic app on browser (**ionic serve**)
4. This HTTP call only fails when I emulate it on my windows platform (**ionic cordova emulate windows**)

Comment: This is cors issue right?

Comment: I think it is, but I have honestly run out of ideas. I have set up CORS headers on my node app. But I am afraid if the HTTP call isn't even leaving my Ionic app as some wrapper is preventing it.

Comment: If the calls are working in the browser, I doubt its being blocked in the code. Possibly something to do with the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this. Apparently, in order to build for windows platforms where private networking is necessary, an extra capability needs to be added manually before building.

Add the following code in your 
/app-x/platforms/windows/package.windows.appxmanifest and 
/app-x/platforms/windows/package.windows10.appxmanifest files.

```
<Capabilities><Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" /></Capabilities>
```